# How to use walk to silently plot ggplot2 output with purrr

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I am trying to understand how to use `walk` to silently (without printing to the console) return `ggplot2` plots in a pipeline.

```
library(tidyverse)

# EX1: This works, but prints [[1]], [[2]], ..., [[10]] to the console
10 %>%
  rerun(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5)) %>%
  map(~ data.frame(.x)) %>%
  map(~ ggplot(., aes(x, y)) + geom_point())

# EX2: This does not plot nor print anything to the console
10 %>%
  rerun(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5)) %>%
  map(~ data.frame(.x)) %>%
  walk(~ ggplot(., aes(x, y)) + geom_point())

# EX3: This errors: Error in obj_desc(x) : object 'x' not found
10 %>%
  rerun(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5)) %>%
  map(~ data.frame(.x)) %>%
  pwalk(~ ggplot(.x, aes(.x$x, .x$y)) + geom_point())

# EX4: This works with base plotting
10 %>%
  rerun(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5)) %>%
  map(~ data.frame(.x)) %>%
  walk(~ plot(.x$x, .x$y))
```

I was expecting example #2 to work, but I must be missing or not understanding something. I want the plots from #1 without the console output.

Comment: `walk` doesn't return or print anything, so if you want to print your plots, you need to say that explicitly. You can wrap the `ggplot` statement inside a `print` call

Comment: @camille - ah, thank you, feel free to answer -- however, still slightly confused -- added example #4 which works with base plotting.

Comment: `walk` returns its input invisibly. Using your EX2, if you run  `p = 10 %>%
  rerun(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5)) %>%
  map(~ data.frame(.x)) %>%
  walk(~ ggplot(., aes(x, y)) + geom_point())` and then type `p`, you'll see that `p` contains the input list of data frames.

Comment: EX1 will not print the individual plots or the list element numbers to the console if you pipe it into something else. For example, `library(gridExtra); 10 %>%
  rerun(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5)) %>%
  map(~ data.frame(.x)) %>%
  map(~ ggplot(., aes(x, y)) + geom_point()) %>% 
  grid.arrange(grobs=., ncol=5)`. Or, with a single call to map: `10 %>%
  rerun(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5)) %>%
  map(~ data.frame(.x) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
          geom_point()) %>% 
  grid.arrange(grobs=., ncol=5)`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure why it works with base R `plot` in your 4th example honestly. But for `ggplot`, you need to explicitly tell `walk` that you want it to print. Or as the comments suggest, `walk` will return plots (I misspoke in my first comment on that) but not print them. So you could use `walk` to save the plots, then write a second statement to print them. Or do it in one `walk` call.

Two things here: I'm using function notation inside `walk`, instead of `purrr`'s abbreviated `~` notation, just to make it clearer what's going on. I also changed the 10 to 4, just so I'm not flooding everyone's screens with tons of plots.

```r
library(tidyverse)

4 %>%
    rerun(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5)) %>%
    map(~ data.frame(.x)) %>%
    walk(function(df) {
        p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
        print(p)
    })
```

[image][image][image][image]

Created on 2018-05-09 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Not directly related but as some migh make the same mistakes as I did, note that one can't pipe a `%>% print` statement to your `ggplot` chain, as because of operator precedence it will print only the last element of the chain (`geom_point` here). So one must either start the whole chain with `print(` or use an additional line like in this answer.

Answer (score -2):

This should work

```
10 %>%
  rerun(x = rnorm(5), y = rnorm(5)) %>%
  map(~ data.frame(.x)) %>%
  map(function(x) {
      ggplot(x, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
  })
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's issue of `map` printing out numbers, such as `[[1]]`

Comment: You're right. I upvoted your answer, it worked pretty well. :D