# Creating tabs automatically in rmarkdown and plotting with purrr

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, knitr, purrr

I am trying to do something similar to what is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63397427/programmatically-create-tab-and-plot-in-markdown).

In a automated way, creating tabs which each contains one plot. Using `hchart` I get the same results, but can replicate it using `ggplot`.

In this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43752095/programmatically-insert-header-and-plot-in-same-code-chunk-with-r-markdown-using), they use `ggplot` instead, but they use a for-loop instead of `purrr`, but I try to add also `cat('\n')` at the end like it is mentioned here, but I still don't get the same results.

## Iris test

```
cat('## Tabs panel {.tabset}   \n')
  iris %>% 
      dplyr::group_split(Species) %>% 
      purrr::imap(.,~{
        # create tabset for each group 
        cat('### Tab',.y,'   \n')
        p <- ggplot(.x, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
        print(p)
        cat('\n')
      })
```

This is the code that produces the closest output, but in the latest tab I get this annoying

`[[1]] NULL`
`[[2]] NULL`
`[[3]] NULL`

output which I am not able to remove.

[image]

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: (Not trying to promote my own answers, it's just the one I knew of) Not exactly the same but the same underlying concept: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50257080/5325862

Comment: Hi @camille. I wish I had found that post before so I could use walk and not adding a new question. But, since I didn't know that walk was going to solve my issue, it was unlikely to find your answer. But, thanks for sharing it :)

Comment: You could mark yours as a duplicate of that one if you want, although on the surface the questions aren't the same. The `purrr` docs link to the [chapter](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html#walk) of R for Data Science that goes through the `map` and `walk` families of functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `imap` to `iwalk`

```
cat('## Tabs panel {.tabset}   \n')
  iris %>% 
      dplyr::group_split(Species) %>% 
      purrr::iwalk(.,~{
        # create tabset for each group 
        cat('### Tab',.y,'   \n')
        p <- ggplot(.x, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
        print(p)
        cat('\n')
      })
```

According to `?walk`

> walk() returns the input .x (invisibly). This makes it easy to use in pipe.

Comment: To get this to work as expected, I had to add an additional line break to the the final `cat` call, i.e. `cat('\n\n')`